# Singleton and ABI stability

Tags: c++, abi

Consider the following class

```
// in library 
class A {
  public:
    static A* instance(){
       static A self;
       return &self;
    }
    void foo() { }
  private:
    A () {}
    int a{0};
};
```

that is defined in dynamic library.

Then a new version of the class is defined with an extra field `b`.

```
class A {
  // as before
  private:
   
    int b{0};
};
```

Is the new version of the library breaking the ABI ?

For a regular class, I would say yes undoubtedly, but for a singleton I think it's /not/ a ABI break (the application handles only pointers to `A` which didn't changed, nothing public changed). But I'm not sure and I would like a definitive answer.

Comment: It's breaks the One-Definition-Rule and anyone using `class A` needs to re-compile see: [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).  _"...One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire program (including any standard and user-defined libraries). The compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined...."_

Comment: The pointer alignment *could* change. Would that be considered an ABI change?

Comment: And if the class is defined in a header then things could be inlined and optimized. Even just changing `int a{0};` to `int a{1}` would break the ABI. You have to move definitions out of the header.

Comment: This is one of the issues I have with singletons in general, they make code inflexible and hard to maintain.
Try if you can refactor to a situation where your main code creates a class (derived from an abstract baseclass) that you can inject in the code that needs acces to it. As a bonus your code will move one step closer to being unit testable.

Answer (score 3):

If the application code ever needs a *complete type* for `A` in order to compile, then yes this would be an ABI break.

If the application merely stores a pointer to `A` (and calls into the library to obtain an `A*`) then there is no ABI break.

Comparisons can be made here with the `FILE*` pointer of C.

The fact that `A` is a singleton is a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

First, with regards to guarantees by the standard, changing any single token in the class definition requires all translation units (including libraries) to use the new definition in order to not break the ODR and cause undefined behavior.

Obviously there are situations in practice where you can rely on the implementation-specific behavior to still make it work and not break ABI in the practical sense.

In the case you are showing, at the very least the `instance` function will be a problem. This function is an inline function and must know the actual exact layout of `A`. But because it is an inline function you cannot control that both the library and the library user will use the same version of this function. You can easily get a mismatch and then the object might be constructed with the wrong layout.

Even if you make `instance` non-`inline`, you will have the same issue with the constructor which is also `inline` in your code.